# How can I translate a String to another String using a given dictionary list in Haskell?

Tags: dictionary, haskell, tuples, encode, translate

I've made a list of tuples:

```
dic = zip(['a' .. 'z') (['o' .. ])
```

It should work to infinite list too, so I was thinking I can't use recursion or list comprehension. Then what? :D
The result should be something like this:

```
dic :: [Char] -> [Char]
dic "abc" = "opq"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should wrap back from `'z'` to `'a'`, so your `dic` would look something like:

```hs
dic :: [(Char, Char)]
dic = zip ['a'..'z'] (['o'..'z'] ++ ['a'..])
```

Now, you can just look up the characters from the list:

```hs
func :: [Char] -> [Char]
func = map (\x ->
    case lookup x dic of
        Just v -> v
        otherwise -> x)
```

Or, with [`fromMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) from `Data.Maybe`:

```hs
import Data.Maybe

func :: [Char] -> [Char]
func = map (\x -> fromMaybe x $ lookup x dic)
```

This works (along with recursive/list comprehension solutions) with infinite char lists due to lazy evaluation: if a value isn't used, then it isn't calculated.